# SQL regular expression to get numbers and commas

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I want to get a substring `2,3` from a text like:
`subscribed lists 2, 3 and opened case 8`

The thing is, I'm not sure how many numbers there will be after `subscribed lists`, not sure if there will be anything after that. So it might also be

`subscribed lists 2`

`subscribed lists 2, 6`

I've tried `select substring(target_expression,'subscribed lists (?!,$)[\d,.]*')` or

`select substring(target_expression,'subscribed lists [\d+,]+')`
(plan to remove `subsribed lists` later)

but I only get `subscribed lists 2,` can't get the numbers after that.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try [`subscribed lists \d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/Xno9DZ/1)?

Comment: [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c8348b/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to get the numbers only, you need to use a capturing group in your pattern that matches them:

```sql
select substring(txt,'subscribed\s+lists\s+(\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)')
```

SQL demo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  txt character varying
);
INSERT INTO test (txt) VALUES ('subscribed lists 2');
INSERT INTO test (txt) VALUES ('subscribed lists 2, 6');

select substring(txt,'subscribed\s+lists\s+(\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)') from test;
```

Output:

| substring |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2, 6 |

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XYniAA/1).

*Details*:

- `subscribed\s+lists\s+` - `subscribed`, one or more whitespaces, `lists`, and one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)` - Group 1: one or more digits (`\d+`) and then zero or more occurrences of a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces and then one or more digits

Answer (score -1):

Actually I tried this and it worked

`select substring(target_expression,'subscribed lists [\d,|\d ]+')`

Comment: cos the numbers are either ```2,``` or  ```3 ```, I didn't consider the later one

Comment: The pattern is the same as `subscribed lists [\d, ]+`